# Pandas treat 'None' value as NaN in one column and as 'None' in other column...?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

| Fluor | Comment |
| --- | --- |
| Strong | None |
| None | None |
| None | Yes |

I have a csv file, while reading it in pandas, Fluor column's None treat as NaN but Comment column's None treat as 'None'.

I don't understand the behavior, I want to treat None as string.

Please guide me.

Comment: Can you provide your python/pandas version and the exact csv? I can't reproduce your issue

Comment: Python: 3.10.4
Pandas: 2.0.0

sorry about the file, can't share it.

Comment: Please show the csv file **as TEXT**, along with the *exact* way you load it in Pandas. Spreadsheet programs are known to *interprete* original data in a way which is not necessarily consistant with the way Pandas does.

Comment: @BKP it would be important to share some original file (a mockup one that reproduces the issue if you're afraid of sensitive data). My answer below should help you to solve the issue but not to explain the behavior that you describe (two columns behaving differently)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I observed that with pandas==2.0.0 I'm facing above problem, but with pandas==1.5.3 treat Blank Cells as NaN and 'None' as 'None'(the usual behavior).

Thanks to all who responded.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your issue in which one columns behaves differently.

However, by default, [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) treats `None` as `NaN`, if you want to prevent this, pass an explicit list of `na_values`:

```
allowed_nans = ['', '#N/A', '#N/A N/A', '#NA', '-1.#IND', '-1.#QNAN',
                '-NaN', '-nan', '1.#IND', '1.#QNAN', '<NA>', 'N/A', 'NA',
                'NULL', 'NaN', 'n/a', 'nan', 'null']

df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', na_values=allowed_nans, keep_default_na=False)

print(df)
```

This should enable you to have None as a string.

*Note that I'm listing here all default values except for `None`, you can of course only keep those that are relevant to you.*

You can also avoid all NaNs:

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', keep_default_na=False)
```

Output:

```
    Fluor Comment
0  Strong    None
1    None    None
2    None     Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all the NaN and None to string "None" using the replace function. This is very vague solution but will help.

```
df = df.replace("NaN", "None")
df = df.replace("None", "None")
df = df.replace(np.nan, "None")

# or any other form of NaN or None.
```